# Inserting VARCHAR like '10/14/2017' into another table as a DATE datatype

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2

Problem: I need to convert VARCHAR values that look like '10/17/2017', or '3/3/2017' into DATE datatype values while INSERTing them into another table.

Scenario - I have an intermediate table that is populated using BULK INSERT from a csv file, requiring that the datatype for all columns in the intermediate table be VARCHAR (unlike SQL Server 2012, where I was able to use the DATE datatype). This is why the VARCHAR dates look like '3/3/2017'.

I have read many similar questions on StackOverflow and have not found a solution.

---

Some obvious things I've tried:

These examples successfully convert the VARCHAR to DATE properly, when tested outside of an INSERT operation:

```
SELECT CAST (importantDate AS DATE)
SELECT CAST(convert(datetime, '8/15/2007', 101) AS DATE)
```

result: `2007-08-15`

---

However, these conversions fail when used inside an INSERT/SELECT statement:

```
INSERT into finalTable 
( convertedDate )
SELECT CAST(convert(datetime, importantDate, 101) AS DATE)
FROM intermediateTable

INSERT into finalTable 
( convertedDate )
SELECT CAST(importantDate AS DATE)
FROM intermediateTable
```

The resulting error is:
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

This is unexpected behavior; I am not sure why this doesn't work. Perhaps I am overlooking something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there are some rows that have data that can't be converted, check  it. One solution is to use a cursor and go row by row, catching conversion exceptions to find out the offending rows

Comment: I have limited my test data to 9 rows; these all have values like 10/14/2017

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the data. My co-worker has pointed out that there was a space in the varchar that I didn't catch. The space needs removed, and you need to account for values with different lengths such as 1/1/2017 or 11/11/2017.
Here is his solution:

`select cast(ltrim(replace(replace(replace(allocationDate,char(9),' '),char(10),' '),char(13),' ')) as date)`

to remove this extra space and successfully insert that value.